# Windows Universal App grouped ListView issue

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I need some help in creating a grouped `ListView` for an **Universal Windows App**.
I found an example to do that but it was for windows 8 phone, and it was using `CollectionViewSource` class and bind the `ListView` `ItemsSource` to it. But this is not available anymore, at least for **Universal Windows App** template.
Please Help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default XAML control for UWP that represents Expandable Listview.
However you can create your own or use custom one. Below you can find two possible solutions:

1. First one - I have created "Expandable ListView" like on the picture below.
   You can find whole source code on my GitHub:

https://github.com/Daniel-Krzyczkowski/Windows10/tree/master/ExpandableListView

[image]

2. Second solution is to use "WinRTXAMLToolkit" which contains TreeView control:

https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit

Here you can find the post how to customize the control:

[WinRT XAML Toolkit TreeView expanded display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28201232/winrt-xaml-toolkit-treeview-expanded-display)

Hope that I helped.